# What's required to do header-based ("SPV") mining possible in Ethereum?

Tags: mining, light-clients, dag

In Bitcoin, one can start mining by just including the header of the previous block into the new block without fully validating it. This is risky, but has speed improvements (being able to start mining sooner).

Is this type of mining possible in Ethereum? What are the requirements? Does the DAG or other hashes involved make this impossible? Or is it equally possible?

Comment: Interesting question. The DAG, however, is still required. But that could also be generated on a light client based on block height.